# Flutter and provider: How do i make my custom listview update automatically?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-provider

What i want to achieve is to have my listview update automatically when the addtoBucketlist fucntion inside the createbucketlistpage is called. Currently the first instance works but when i proceed to add another the listview doesnt update and i have to navigate away from the bucketlistpage and back before i can see the changes.

I am generating a list of widgets on the createbucketlistpage where users can click on a particular widget and it should get added to the bucket list page automatically.

Heres my provider code

```
class UpcomingTour extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> upcomingTourImages = [
    'assets/UpcomingToursImages/ut1.jpg',
    'assets/UpcomingToursImages/ut2.jpg',
    'assets/UpcomingToursImages/ut3.jpg',
  ];

  List<String> upComingTourTitle = [
    'Kruger',
    'Camping and Hiking Ilorin',
    'Labadi Beach',
  ];

  List<String> upcomingTourDate = [
    'Loading...',
    'Loading...',
    'Loading...',
  ];

  List<Widget> upcomingTourBody = [
    //kruger
    const Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Text(
          '''The big five: Elephant, Lion, Rhino, Leopard and Buffalo. Kruger park is home to a stunning diversity of wildlife, trees, flowers and most importantly The big five. Steeped in legend and history with exquisite accomodations and meals. Kruger national park is one of the most famous tourist destinations in the world. To get the real taste of a safari tour, book a tour to Kruger national park.'''),
    ),
    //camping
    const Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Text(
          '''Enjoy one of the best outdoor activities in the world in the beautiful city of Ilorin.
Our world has changed drastically since the pandemic and many people are feeling more isolated. Work from home has become the norm for many and social media, email and the general 24/7 noise of life can leave us more stressed out.
Disconnecting from technology and reconnecting with nature gives our brain a much-needed recharge, especially among those with sedentary occupations. Camping and Hiking helps you reconnect with nature, build better relationships and aids in overall physical and mental fitness'''),
    ),
    // labadi beach
    const Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Text(
          '''Also known as La pleasure beach. Labadi beach is one of the best beaches on the Ghana coast, filled with lots and lots of fun activities such as games, horse riding and most importantly, relaxing. Labadi beach is perfect for both couple and family vacations.'''),
    ),
  ];
  var newUpcomingTour;
  List<Padding> upcomingTourList = [];

// The original function to generate a list of Upcoming tour widgets
  List<Padding> getUpcomingTour(BuildContext context) {
    for (int i = 0; i < upcomingTourImages.length; i++) {
      String imagePath = upcomingTourImages[i];
      String title = upComingTourTitle[i];
      String desc = upcomingTourDate[i];
      newUpcomingTour = Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(10)),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        imagePath,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(
                            title,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(desc),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Provider.of<UpcomingTour>(context, listen: false)
                          .addToBucketList(upcomingTourList[i]);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        child: Icon(Icons.add),
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
      upcomingTourList.add(newUpcomingTour);
    }
    return upcomingTourList;
 }

  List<Padding> bucketList = [];

  void addToBucketList(Padding item) {
    bucketList.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeFromBucketList(Padding item) {
    bucketList.remove(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void clearBucketList() {
    bucketList.clear();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The code above contains the function that generates the list of widgets that are displayed in the create bucket list page

Heres the code for my create bucketlist page

```
class _BucketListPageContentsState extends State<BucketListPageContents> {
  String searchInput = '';
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  UpcomingTour upcomingTour = UpcomingTour();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'Create your explore bucket list',
                style: kBoldTextStyleBlack,
              ),
              addVerticalSpacing(20),
              const Text(
                  'Let’s make your dreams come true. Tell us where you would like to visit or an event you would like to attend and we might just make it happen'),
              addVerticalSpacing(20),
              const Text(
                'Add from upcoming tours',
                style: kBoldTextStyleBlack,
              ),
              addVerticalSpacing(20),
            ],
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: ListView(
              children: upcomingTour.getUpcomingTour(context),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And finLally heres the bucketlistpage

```
class BucketList extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'Bucketlistpage';

  const BucketList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BucketList> createState() => _BucketListState();
}

class _BucketListState extends State<BucketList> {
  int? bucketListlength;
  UpcomingTour upcomingTour = UpcomingTour();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bucketListlength = Provider.of<UpcomingTour>(context).bucketList.length;

    if (bucketListlength == 0) {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              tooltip: 'Add new tour to Bucketlist',
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    PageTransition(
                        child: const CreateBucketListPage(),
                        type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft));
              }),
          body: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: ListView(scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.41,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      image: AssetImage('assets/emptybucketlist.jpg'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  'BucketList is Empty',
                  style: kBoldTextStyleBlack,
                ),
              ),
              addVerticalSpacing(20),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text(
                    'Let’s make your dreams come true. Add places/events you woud like to visit/attend. '),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              tooltip: 'Add new tour to BucketList',
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        PageTransition(
                            child: const CreateBucketListPage(),
                            type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft))
                    .then((value) => setState(() {}));
              }),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  key: const Key('upcomingTour'),
                  children: Provider.of<UpcomingTour>(context, listen: true)
                      .bucketList,
                ),
              ),
              ReusableButton(const Text('Clear BucketList'), () {
                Provider.of<UpcomingTour>(context, listen: false)
                    .clearBucketList();
              })
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

i cannot use listview.builder because my widgets are already being generated by a fucntion and i dont need to build them as they are being added manually by the user.

Heres my idea is to listen for the changes in the length of the bucketlist list in the provider model and use it to show an empty bucketlist page if the length of the bucketlist list is 0 or show the list.
I am new to provider and ihave tried different things from tutorials but none worked. I even changed from Change notifier to value notifier but it didnt work.

I have also tried different ways to refresh the bucketlist page when i pop from createbucketlistpage but that too doesnt work.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use Consumer in your page whenever your Data Changes your widget will rebuild automatically (when using notifyListiners method ), also its a performance wise to use Consumer which is rebuild only the widget inside the Consumer not the whole page and that will provide a better performance for your app
here is an example:

```
Consumer<yourProviderType>(
builder:(context, value, child) => value.yourList.isEmpty
                ? CircularProgressIndicator():
build a widget which contain data comes from the value instnace
)
```

Comment: This solution didnt work.

Comment: when you need to update your element automatically you  have 2 ways:
1- Provider Consumer (google it to learn more about it)
2- Provider.of<yourProvier>(context) approach inside your build Widget
there is no other solution using Provider Package

Comment: Perhaps the solution cannot be found with provider.

Comment: I will try to use apis to solve this problem. Thanks for your input.